# Is it possible to configure LyX to stop jumping to the first error location after compilation?

Tags: errors, lyx

I have a LyX document which contains some errors due to a 3rd party template.

Even though the errors are flagged, the output is fine and fixing this complex template is not my priority.

However, after compilation, be it with "View" or "Update", the "LaTeX errors" dialog pops and the document jumps to the first instance of the mentioned errors.

Is there a way to disable the automatic jumping behaviour (or remove the warning/error dialog altogether?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no LyX option to do this for you. The only way I can think of would be to define your own LyX converter, which empties the log right after compiling. To do this, see Help > Customization. It will take a lot of time though if you're not familiar with LyX converters, and I get the feeling you don't have time for this particular task.